# ROOT file not getting executed

Tags: c++, linux, machine-learning, terminal, root-framework

I am learning ROOT for ONNX-CERN project. While running the TMVAClassifier file in root terminal.

I followed the steps mentioned in the tutorial and wrote the following line:

```
 root -l ./TMVAClassification.C\(\"Fisher,Likelihood\"\)
```

But, the file is not getting executed and the line prompt is changed to below:

```
root (cont'ed, cancel with .@)
```

Here is the [link](https://root.cern/doc/master/TMVAClassification_8C.html) for the TMVAClassification file.
Requesting help, in executing the classification file in ROOT.

Comment: The "root" tag you applied has nothing to do with the ROOT large-data data analysis framework (tag removed).  I don't think we presently have a tag for that, and I'm uncertain whether we need one because it's not clear to me to what extent questions related to that framework are on-topic here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger even after removing the root tag the output is same. As per the guidelines and tutorial to run a root file I need to mention the root tag. The framework is of  Toolkit for Multivariate Data Analysis (TMVA), and the model used is a Classification model. Here is the link for what I am trying to do. https://root.cern/manual/tmva/

Comment: Of course the output is the same.  How would my removing a tag from your SO post change the behavior of the program?  My previous comment was about a moderation action I performed, not an attempt to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work:

```
root -l './TMVAClassification.C("Fisher,Likelihood")'
```

If it does not, please let us know you ROOT version. The correct syntax is different for different ROOT versions.